# Non-invertible mapping of a random vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, geometric-probability

Suppoe that $X$ is a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ with density $p_{X}$ which is absolutely continuous, and let $f:\mathbb{R}^{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{M}$ be a non-invertible function, where $M<N$.
Define $Y=f(X)$.
Is there a function $g:\mathbb{R}^{M}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N}$ such that $p_{Z}=p_{X}$, where $Z=g(Y)=g(f(X))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. To consider a simple counterexample, assume $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_N)$, the standard normal distribution and $f(x_1,...,x_n)=1\{x_1\geq 0\}$. Then $Y$ is binary and thus the support of $Z$ has at most two values.